# Do reads from another stored procedure count for REPEATABLE READ

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Imagine I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckIfDataIsOk]
AS
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    -- bunch of checks that read row 1

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

**Edit**: I put `READ UNCOMMITTED` in the stored procedure, but it could have been `READ COMMITTED` too. The point is that this first stored procedure is returning a result purely based on reading data in a table.

And I then want to use it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DoSomethingImportant]
AS
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    EXECUTE [dbo].[CheckIfDataIsOk]

    -- if "data is ok", then do some work that modifies row1

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Will the "repeatable read" isolation level put a read-lock when it reads data from row1 indirectly through the first stored procedure call? Or will it put the lock only when it touches row1 in the stored procedure itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing one stored procedure from another, the execution context changes. When control returns, any changes to the execution context (such as `SET` options or isolation level) are rolled back to what they were before.

So when you execute

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ

BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

the isolation level is changed.

---

However, upon executing

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[CheckIfDataIsOk]
```

the context is saved, so that it can be rolled back afterwards.

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckIfDataIsOk]
AS
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- bunches of checks that read row 1

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

here the isolation level is changed for the duration of the procedure (note that the inner transaction does not actually commit until the outer one does). So the rows being accessed are not locked.

---

```
-- if "data is ok", then do some work that modifies row1

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

At this point, the original settings are put back into place. However, previously read rows are not yet locked, and could change.

---

Note that `REPEATABLE READ` does not prevent *new* rows being read, it only prevents previously read rows from being changed. [So it may not actually be "repeatable" in the general sense.](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-repeatable-read-isolation-level)

And to behonest, I would change the isolation level from `READ UNCOMMITTED` to something better. It can cause [**completely incorrect results**](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-uncommitted-isolation-level), such as reading pages multiple times, reading data that simply should not be possible according to constraints, etc.

Comment: thanks @Charlieface, that's interesting!
I basically wanted to apply in [DoSomethingImportant] the pattern of 1. checking if the data I have is valid before 2. modifying it. This would have worked if the stored proc [CheckIfDataIsOk] was inlined into [DoSomethingImportant].
It seems that by trying to also expose [CheckIfDataIsOk] as its own stored proc, I can't really reuse its code while keeping correct isolation levels

Comment: Yes you can: just use a good isolation level such as `REPEATABLE READ`. Why would you ever use `READ UNCOMMITTED` anyway?

Comment: [CheckIfDataIsOk]  used as stand-alone is purely reading data and checking if the data is valid. I think indeed READ UNCOMMITTED is too lax for this but I think I would have the same problem I described if it was READ COMMITTED

Comment: You could use an `UPDLOCK` hint with `READ COMMITTED` to enforce that if you want. It shouldn't affect any other readers, whereas `XLOCK` will block later readers. In other words, if you want to be able to use this procedure for both readers and writers, `UPDLOCK` makes a lot of sense

Comment: But would the UPDLOCK  hold until the end of the call to [DoSomethingImportant] ?

Comment: Yes, it would, as it's part of the same transaction. You can prove this by running this script on your own SQL Server https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=11187d19e3946050c50def1705eca9ca (doesn't work on that site due to permissions)

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't use READ UNCOMMITED/NOLOCK.  You can and will get incorrect results in the presence of concurrent transactions.  And here where you

> if "data is ok", then do some work that modifies row1

using READ UNCOMMITTED is simply, and clearly wrong.  When reading a row that you intend to modify, you should use a restrictive lock, not just a Shared lock (or NOLOCK).   When reading a row in a transaction that you intend to modify, you should read with an UPDLOCK hint.

2. The behavior is clearly explained in the docs:

> With one exception, you can switch from one isolation level to another
> at any time during a transaction. The exception occurs when changing
> from any isolation level to SNAPSHOT isolation. Doing this causes the
> transaction to fail and roll back. However, you can change a
> transaction started in SNAPSHOT isolation to any other isolation
> level.
>
> When you change a transaction from one isolation level to another,
> resources that are read after the change are protected according to
> the rules of the new level. Resources that are read before the change
> continue to be protected according to the rules of the previous level.
> For example, if a transaction changed from READ COMMITTED to
> SERIALIZABLE, the shared locks acquired after the change are now held
> until the end of the transaction.
>
> If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in a stored procedure or
> trigger, when the object returns control the isolation level is reset
> to the level in effect when the object was invoked. For example, if
> you set REPEATABLE READ in a batch, and the batch then calls a stored
> procedure that sets the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE, the isolation
> level setting reverts to REPEATABLE READ when the stored procedure
> returns control to the batch.

[SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: ok so maybe my initial stored proc should have READ COMMITTED.
Is there a way to force the rows read through the stored proc to be locked for reading when called through the 2nd stored proc ?

Comment: No isolation level will prevent reads by other transactions.  If you want that you can use a n XLOCK table hint in a query in a transaction.

Comment: In my case I'm just talking about a stored proc called from a stored proc, so a transaction within a transaction